# Rails fetch all including last row from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, eager-loading

I have two model with has_many belongs to relation.

```
Scheme has_many navs
```

I need to fetch all the Schemes with only last nav value. I have 10 Schemes and each scheme has around 100k navs but I need only last record which is the current value.

With eager loading will load all the navs

```
Scheme.all.includes(:navs)
```

How can I apply condition to to get only last row of nav for each schemes while eager loading.

**UPDATE with Log**

If I run

```
Scheme.includes(:current_nav).limit(3)
```

these are the queries executed by AR

```
SELECT  `schemes`.* FROM `schemes`  LIMIT 3
SELECT `navs`.* FROM `navs`  WHERE `navs`.`schemeCode` IN ('D04', 'D01', 'D30')  ORDER BY id DESC
```

How the second query works, it will take all the navs whose schemeCode falls under list and order those by id DESC , but how it will be associated with particular scheme exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about creating an another association like this:

```
class Scheme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :current_nav, -> { order('id DESC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Nav'
end
```

Now you can:

```
Schema.includes(:current_nav).all
```

or:

```
Schema.includes(:current_nav).last(10)
```

will eager load only last nav of the queried schemes.

**Explanation**: [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) is one of the methods for retrieving objects from database in `ActiveRecord`. From the doc itself:

> Active Record lets you specify in advance all the associations that
>   are going to be loaded. This is possible by specifying the includes
>   method of the Model.find call. With includes, Active Record ensures
>   that all of the specified associations are loaded using the minimum
>   possible number of queries.

And, since we have the association setup with `current_nav`, all we had to do is to use it with `includes` to eager load the data. Please read [ActiveRecord querying doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more information.

Comment: Did it work the way you were expecting? I'll add the explanation soon.

Comment: Its fetching results , but if you give explanation it will be very great , since it works like magic.

Comment: @Senthil : Added explanation, I am glad that your problem is solved. I thought I wouldn't need to say it, but since I am overwhelmed by OPs on SO for not accepting answers even if it helps, so, kindly accept answer of your question on SO if they solves your problem. Have a happy programming.